# Why are there multiple POST requests with /FotorShopSurpport API on my AWS Elastic Bean Stalk node server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I see multiple POST requests throughout my logs:

```
POST /FotorShopSurpport/fetchModulesByAppkey
POST /FotorShopSurpport/fetchRecommendResource
POST /FotorShopSurpport/batchResourcePkgNumByType
```

I don't have any API matching that route neither am I calling this APIs on my server. I recently created this server and no one even knows link to the server apart from me.

Is this something Elastic Beanstalk doing? Or is it totally different?

I have several other servers through elastic beanstalk and these requests are the first time I have seen in any logs.

Comment: Either it could be that there was another server on the IP address before and you are seeing people still trying to access that  Or possibly someone scanning for a vulnerable API and they are doing this across a wide range of IP addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some access logs containing "FotorShopSurpport" on google. The requests are for store.fotor.com.

```
$ host store.fotor.com
store.fotor.com is an alias for elb-store-376424179.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb-store-376424179.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com has address 52.34.194.249
elb-store-376424179.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com has address 35.160.57.75
```

Some client trying to access store.fotor.com is using the wrong IP, maybe because of too agressive caching. ELB keeps changing IPs. I have seen such request in my access logs too. Make sure your webserver is configured to only serve requests for your own hostnames.